# How to read a NSMutableArray out of a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am having problems reading out a mutable array out of a mutable dictionary.  I am trying to read it out, and then put it into a label.  Here is how my data is organized.  I have a mutable array of dictionaries.  Then in my tableview I take the object at index path and set it equal to a dictionary in the app delegate.  Then in the details view I load the dictionary that I took out of the array and I read from it and put the values into the labels.  I have all the strings in the dictionary working, but the arrays won't read out, can you help me

RootViewController.m

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SurveyAppAppDelegate *surveyAppAppDelegate = (SurveyAppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    SurveyViewer *surveyViewController = [[SurveyViewer alloc] initWithNibName:@"SurveyViewer" bundle:nil]; 
    surveyAppAppDelegate.arrayCount = [[self surveyArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:surveyViewController animated:YES];
    [surveyViewController release];
}
```

In my App Delegate it is set as NSDictionary.

Then in my detail view controller I do this

```
  injuredArray = [surveyAppAppDelegate.arrayCount objectForKey:@"Injured Part"];

    if ([injuredArray count] >= 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i<=([injuredArray count]-1); i++) {
            myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 105+shift, 139, 15)];
            myLabel.text = [injuredArray objectAtIndex:i];
            myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size: 14.0];
            myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            [self.theScroller addSubview:myLabel];
            shift = shift+20;
        }
    }
```

In my App Delegate I set up arrayCount like this

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class RootViewController;

    @interface SurveyAppAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
        NSDictionary *arrayCount;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSDictionary *arrayCount;

    @end
```

and .m

```
#import "SurveyAppAppDelegate.h"
@implementation SurveyAppAppDelegate
    @synthesize arrayCount;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {


        arrayCount = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

Then in the dealloc of the app delegate I release it

Oh, and the objects in the NSMutableArray that I set to injuredArray are all strings

EDIT: So I added a loop to NSLog the array in the root view controller right after I set it, and it isn't working.  So it looks for some reason that it isn't being saved in arrayCount correctly

Thanks for your help

Comment: In your detail view controller, where is the reference to surveyAppAppDelegate coming from? Are you sure it's not null?

Comment: Yes, I set it to a NSDictionary, do the property and synthesize, then I initialize it like this  arrayCount = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

Comment: What is the value of injuredArray ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your appDelegate header, try retaining the dictionary instead of assigning:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *arrayCount;
```

then in implementation:

```
NSDictionary *anArrayCount = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
self.arrayCount = anArrayCount;
[anArrayCount release];
```

Is the injuredArray object you're assigning already allocated and initialized? That could be the problem...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I think the problem was that I was putting a mutable array into the dictionary or something, Im not 100% sure, all I know is that after a bit of tinkering it works now

Comment: I ran into some more problems later with the same type of issues, it was solved by retaining the dictionary, I meant to retain it as I normally do, must've been a typo :/  Don't you hate those, cause when it is proper syntax and doesn't bring up an error message they are so hard to catch

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating an init method in your detail view controller that accepts the NSDictionary that your are interested in and retains it in a property. I cannot tell where this reference in coming from: surveyAppAppDelegate.arrayCount

Comment: Yeah I did that, you can look in the original post, I posted my app delegate code